# How can I place a rectangle over a javascript rendered div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wavesurfer.js

I am working with a waveform display/play library called [wavesurfer](https://wavesurfer-js.org/).  In the snippet that I created below, I have two such wavesurfer objects rendered and placed inside "container" type div elements.  I would like to place my own rectangle over one of these wavesurfer objects, and control it's position using javascript.

My problem is I do not want to use absolute coordinates referenced for the browser window.  I want to use relative coordinates based on the position within the wavesurfer object.   Furthermore, as you can see, the rectangle is not overlayed over the waveform, even if I place it within the same div container.

I am new to javascript and realize that this could be a very basic question about overlaying shapes on top of things like pictures, but so far I haven't been able to find a solution that works for the waveform objects I am working with.

```js
var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
  container: "#waveform",
  waveColor: "darkorange",
  progressColor: "skyblue",
  interact: false
});

wavesurfer.load("https://ia902606.us.archive.org/35/items/shortpoetry_047_librivox/song_cjrg_teasdale_64kb.mp3");


var wavesurfer2 = WaveSurfer.create({
  container: "#waveform2",
  waveColor: "silver",
  progressColor: "gainsboro",
  interact: false
});

wavesurfer2.load(  "https://ia902606.us.archive.org/35/items/shortpoetry_047_librivox/song_cjrg_teasdale_64kb.mp3"
);
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/wavesurfer.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/wavesurfer.js/dist/wavesurfer.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/wavesurfer.js/dist/plugin/wavesurfer.regions.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="container" style="display: flex">
  <div id="waveform" style="width:60%"></div>
</div>

<div class="container" style="display: flex">
  <div id="waveform2" style="width:60%"></div>
</div>

  <div>
    <input type="range" id="slider" name="range_slider" min="0" max="11">
    <label for="range_slider">Range Slider</label>
  </div>
  
  
  <div id="selector">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <rect x="10" y="10" width="50" height="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
      </svg>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getBoundingClientRect` to get the offset height and the offset left of the desired element, based on these values you can easly position any element relatively to these values.

As described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52477551/7457356

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach would be to put a pseudo element on each waveform (or on whichever waveform you want).

This can then be positioned in % terms, the % being relative to the width of the waveform.

This snippet draws the rectangle by putting a border round the pseudo element but it could have an image as the background if a less simple shape is required.

A class waveform is introduced to make it simpler to style these elements.

```js
var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
  container: "#waveform",
  waveColor: "darkorange",
  progressColor: "skyblue",
  interact: false
});

wavesurfer.load("https://ia902606.us.archive.org/35/items/shortpoetry_047_librivox/song_cjrg_teasdale_64kb.mp3");


var wavesurfer2 = WaveSurfer.create({
  container: "#waveform2",
  waveColor: "silver",
  progressColor: "gainsboro",
  interact: false
});

wavesurfer2.load("https://ia902606.us.archive.org/35/items/shortpoetry_047_librivox/song_cjrg_teasdale_64kb.mp3");
```

```css
.waveform {
  position: relative;
}

.waveform::before {
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 3;
  border: solid 5px;
  left: var(--left);
}

#waveform {
  --left: 60%;
}

#waveform2 {
  --left: 8%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/wavesurfer.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/wavesurfer.js/dist/wavesurfer.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/wavesurfer.js/dist/plugin/wavesurfer.regions.min.js"></script>

  <div class="container" style="display: flex">
    <div id="waveform" class="waveform" style="width:60%"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="container" style="display: flex">
    <div id="waveform2" class="waveform" style="width:60%"></div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="range" id="slider" name="range_slider" min="0" max="11">
    <label for="range_slider">Range Slider</label>
  </div>
```

CSS variables have been used to set the distance along a waveform that the selector is to sit. For any particular waveform element this can be changed by setting the style --left property e.g. element.style.setProperty('--left', '60%');